# WPF TreeView selected treeviewitem to change property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I wanted to know if what I am trying to achieve is possible.

I have a hierarchical TreeView with custom treeview items, using binding. See below

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="4" x:Name="myTreeView"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Sponsors}">

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Studies}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Style="{StaticResource ExpandingImageStyle}">
                        <Image.Resources>
                            <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Closed" UriSource="/SearchEngine;component/Resources/TreeView/FolderClosed.png"/>
                            <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Open" UriSource="/SearchEngine;component/Resources/TreeView/FolderOpen.png"/>
                        </Image.Resources>
                    </Image>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Sponsor}" ToolTip="{Binding Path}" Padding="5 0 0 0" Style="{StaticResource FolderContextMenuStyle}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Documents}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Style="{StaticResource ExpandingImageStyle}">
                                <Image.Resources>
                                    <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Closed" UriSource="/SearchEngine;component/Resources/TreeView/FolderClosed.png"/>
                                    <BitmapImage x:Key="Icon_Open" UriSource="/SearchEngine;component/Resources/TreeView/FolderOpen.png"/>
                                </Image.Resources>
                            </Image>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="13" Text="{Binding Study}" ToolTip="{Binding Path}" Padding="5 0 0 0" Style="{StaticResource FolderContextMenuStyle}" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <!-- Documents template -->
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Stretch="Uniform" Height="16" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Document}" Padding="5 0 0 0" ToolTip="{Binding Path}" FontSize="13" Style="{StaticResource DocumentContextMenuStyle}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Sponsors, Studies, and Documents are lists of classes which I bind at the three levels of my treeview. See property for Sponsors below from my ViewModel:

```
public List<TreeSponsor> Sponsors
    {
        get
        {
            return _sponsors;
        }
        set
        {
            _sponsors = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Sponsors");
        }
    }
```

And my three classes:

```
public class TreeSponsor
    {
        public string Sponsor { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string ImageSource { get; set; }
        public List<TreeStudy> Studies { get; set; }

        public TreeSponsor(string sponsor, string path)
        //public TreeSponsor()
        {
            Sponsor = sponsor;
            Path = path;
            ImageSource = "/SearchEngine;component/Resources/TreeView/FolderClosed.png";
            Studies = new List<TreeStudy>();
        }
    }

    public class TreeStudy
    {
        public string Study { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string LastDateChange { get; set; }
        public string ImageSource { get; set; }
        public List<TreeDocument> Documents { get; set; }

        public TreeStudy(string study, string path, string date)
        {
            Study = study;
            Path = path;
            LastDateChange = date;
            ImageSource = "/SearchEngine;component/Resources/TreeView/FolderClosed.png";
            Documents = new List<TreeDocument>();
        }
    }

public class TreeDocument
    {
        public string Study { get; set; }
        public string Document { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string ImageSource { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

        public TreeDocument(string study, string document, string path)
        {
            Study = study;
            Document = document;
            Path = path;


            ImageSource = "/SearchEngine;component/Resources/MessageBox/error.png";
        }
    }
```

I have added an IsSelected property to the TreeDocument class which I would like to set to True or False depending on whether the Document is selected in the treeview. This particular node is always the last (third) level of the treeview. How would I achieve this? Maybe with Triggers?

Edit:

Ok I managed to do what I want with the following code and where when I select a Document from the treeview, it updates the property if I click on a treeview item.

```
<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

However, despite binding twoway, I can't seem to set the IsSelected property through code. With the code below which I have in code behind, if the first level of a treeview node is selected (Sponsor), I want to select the first Document (third level) by setting it's IsSelected property to true. But the selection never changes.

```
if (myTreeView.SelectedItem is TreeSponsor)
        {
            TreeSponsor ts = (TreeSponsor)myTreeView.SelectedItem;

            ts.Studies[0].Documents[0].IsSelected = true;
        }
```

Comment: Would it be a problem to add IsSelected to all your classes? You could then add a style making any treeviewitem bind isselected.                             <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

Comment: I did this right before you posted your answer, and it's working fine. I was struggling with the Setter in the XAML, but I got it. Thanks!

Comment: I have a base class with isselected and some other stuff in it which I would inherit such classes from. You probably thought of that already :)

Comment: Can you see my edit at the end of my post? I am having an issue with the solution.

Comment: You have isdocselected in the code and isselected in XAML. Maybe that's a typo though.  Do you need updatesourcetrigger?

Comment: Yes that was a typo sorry. I removed updatesourcetrigger but it still does not select the first document. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Are you sure it's not selecting it? Without focus that might not be very obvious.

Comment: Yes it does not change the treeview selection. It remains focused on the Sponsor node. To be clear, the code which attempts to select the first document is executed from a button press. Could the focus changing away from the treeview to the button be causing it?

Comment: I figured it out. I needed implement INotidyPropertyChanged on TreeDocument and call OnPorpertyChanged in the IsSelected property set.